# Removing files under particular conditions (number of files, file age)

Tags: linux, bash, find

I want to create a shell script that will count files (1 hr older files) and if files are more than 1000, then delete all.

For read and delete I am using those command at putty

for count:

```
ls /tmp/ | grep 'ci_session*' | wc -l
```

for Delete files:

```
cd /tmp/
find . -name "ci_session*" -exec rm {} \;
```

**#Update: for delete, i want to delete only 1 hr older files.**

Here I want to add condition if total files are greater than 1000, then call delete command.

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: Greater than 1000 _what_?  Lines long? Bytes? Or are you wanting to delete only if there are more than 1000 files?

Comment: Are you okay with "Older than 1 hour" meaning last modified greater than 1 hour ago?  Unix operating systems generally don't have a concept of creation time

Comment: @Kusalananda number of files.

Answer (score 7):

I interpreted your question as "How may I count the files, and if there are more than 1000, delete the ones that are older than one hour?".

Counting the names matching `/tmp/ci_session*` and doing something when there's more than 1000 of them:

```
set -- /tmp/ci_session*
if [ "$#" -gt 1000 ]; then
    # something
fi
```

This sets the positional parameters to the names matching the pattern.  The special variable `$#` then contains the number of positional parameters.

Deleting the files matching `/tmp/ci_session*` if their last modified time is more than an hour ago:

```
find /tmp -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'ci_session*' -mmin +60 -delete
```

Taken together:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -- /tmp/ci_session*
if [ "$#" -gt 1000 ]; then
    find /tmp -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'ci_session*' -mmin +60 -delete
fi
```

The only thing to note here is that the count will be of *any* name matching the pattern (even of directory names, if there are any), while the `find` command will restrict the deletion to only *regular files* (i.e. not directories).

Comment: I thought `set` would surely fail with "argument list too long" at some point, but no. I guess because `set` is a built-in?

Comment: @l0b0 Exactly. Built-in utilities do not have any restrictions like that, and `set` is furthermore a _special built-in utility_, which means it needs to always be built into the shell (or it would not be able to set positional parameters nor shell options).

Comment: I am getting this error. /bin/bash: /home/yogeshs/public_html/cleanup.sh: Permission denied

i added sh file at public_html folder then added cron job (* * * * *  /home/yogeshs/public_html/cleanup.sh
  )

Comment: @Kusalananda pls help getting Permission denied

Comment: @YogeshSaroya Either run the script with `sh scriptname` or make it executable with `chmod +x scriptname` and run it as you're trying to now.

Comment: @Kusalananda getting this error (permission is 777)  /home/yogeshs/public_html/abc.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
/home/yogeshs/public_html/abc.sh: line 5: `fi'

Comment: @YogeshSaroya Then you have a syntax error in your code. Make sure the script looks exactly like what I wrote, including spaces and quotes. I can't see your code to point to what's wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91470/discussion-between-yogesh-saroya-and-kusalananda).

Comment: @l0b0: The maximum amount of arguments is often upwards of 100k so it's probably unlikely to reach it if OP is planning to delete these files whenever they exceed 1000.

Comment: @Jesse_b For built in commands, you're more or less restricted by the memory resource limits of the shell process.

Comment: @Kusalananda: Yeah my system simply crashes when I provide a list too long, but it doesn't happen until well over 100 million arguments

Answer (score 5):

As long as your `find` has an `-mmin` option you can do:

Using a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

files_dir=/tmp
file_count=$(find "$files_dir" -name 'ci_session*' -mmin 60 -exec echo x \; | wc -l)

if [ "$file_count" -gt 1000 ]; then
    find "$files_dir" -name 'ci_session*' -mmin 60 -exec rm {} \;
fi
```

`file_count` will be set to the number of files found in the specified directory matching the pattern.

If `file_count` is greater than 1000 we will run find again and delete those files.

---

Using bash we can eliminate the second call to find with an array:

```
#!/bin/bash

files_dir=/tmp
mapfile -t files < <(find "$files_dir" -name 'ci_session*' -mmin 60)

if ((${#files[@]}>1000)); then
    rm "${files[@]}"
fi
```

Note: depending on how many files you expect to have the bash solution may run into your command line argument [limit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19354870/8239155).

Comment: could you please update delete command to delete only 1hr older files ?